# Как сделать доступ к функциям сайта без пароля?

Tags: node.js, express, recaptcha, аутентификация

Использую express.js. В идеале хочу сделать следующее: человек заходит на сайт, выполняет капчу и когда он ее проходит получает какой-нибудь токен, который дает доступ к определенным функциям сайта скажем на 2 часа. Когда время истекает, все что пользователь сделал на сайте стирается из бд, и необходимо опять пройти капчу.

Подскажите минусы такого подхода. А также если такой подход используется, подскажите куда копать для реализации. Я пока что нашел OAuth 2.0, но я не уверен, что это то.

Comment: OAuth чрезмерно сложен для такой простой задачи

Comment: @andreymal подскажите примерную реализацию пожалуйста. Сделать доступ по JWT и отдавать его вместе с удачным ответом капчи?

Comment: Я надеялся на готовое решение, уверен что я не оригинален в этой идее

Comment: Можно и JWT, но и его можно посчитать слишком сложным, можно ведь просто сгенерировать случайную строку, положить её в бд и стереть через два часа, чё мудрить-то

Comment: @andreymal понял спасибо большое! Да я просто думал с заделом на будущее, если бы была библиотека для passport например то поставив другую я бы мог легко перейти на авторизацию через скажем гугл

Comment: Ну тогда, если есть готовая система аутентификации, то наверное вместо случайной строки можно попробовать опять же не мудрить и просто взять то, что выдаёт passport после успешной аутентификации, но я с ним не работал и потому от дальнейших комментариев воздержусь

Comment: JWT вроде подойдет, тем более там сразу есть поддержка expiration, можно даже в базу не класть, если конечно не хотите преждевременно отзывать токен.